# How to fill a ListView in Android with data that comes from an external file and not from res/values/strings.xml file

Tags: android, xml, android-listview

I would like to create a **List View** in an android application.

The data is stored in an **external xml file**, located in assets folder.

**external xml file:**

```
<root>
    <category> books </category>
         <item>
              <title> book Title1 </title>
         </item>
         <item>
              <title> book Title2 </title>
         </item>
         <item>
              <title> book Title3</title>
         </item>
     <category> movies </category>
         <item>
              <title> Title1 </title>
         </item>
         <item>
              <title> Title2 </title>
         </item>
         <item>
              <title> Title3</title>
         </item>
</root>
```

I would like to create a ListView that is going to contain all the books' titles

e.g.

```
book Title1
book Title2
book Title3 etc
```

The **first step** is to use a DOM parser in order to parse the external xml document and take all the books' titles with xpath.*(I have done that)*

The **second step** is to fill the ListView with those values *(I have not done that cause i don't know which is the best way to do that)*.

I read some examples online, in this examples the data is stored in strings.xml file.
In my case the data is dynamic, comes from a relational database and is stored in an xml file.

I'm new to android, I would like your advice on that.

I don't know where to store the data that comes from the external xml file in order to fill the ListView in Android.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about some code? The code below assumes the use of Fragments, but you should be able to adapt it (pun intended) to work with any old straight-up Activity:

It sounds like for each ListView item you have two attributes to display:

- Category
- Title

So, the model object might look something like:

```
public class MyItem {
  private String mCategory;
  private String mTitle;
  public String getCategory() {
    return mCategory;
  }
  // Plus other getters/setters.....
}
```

If you want to display more than one field you can use a custom layout, which you will put in `res/layout` (let's call it list_item_myitems.xml):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/list_item_categoryTextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="4dp"
        android:paddingRight="4dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/list_item_titleTextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="4dp"
        android:paddingRight="4dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The layout above will be inflated inside of a `<FrameLayout>` when using Fragments. If you are not using Fragments, then include the two `<TextView>` items above below your `<ListView>` element in your activity's layout XML.

Next, how about a custom adapter class to handle rendering the View that is displayed for each ListView item?

```
public class MyItemAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<MyItem> {

  public MyItemAdapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<MyItem> items) {
    super(activity, 0, items);
  }

  @Override
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View ret;
    if (convertView == null) {
      convertView = getActivity().
        getLayoutInflater().
        inflate(R.layout.list_item_myitems, null);
    }

    MyItem item = getItem(position);

    TextView dateTextView = 
      (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_categoryTextView);
    dateTextView.setText(item.getCategory());

    TextView titleTextView =     
      (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_titleTextView);
    titleTextView.setText(item.getTitle());

     ret = convertView;
     return ret;
   }


}
```

In your ListFragment subclass (or Activity subclass - probably a ListActivity subclass), create the custom adapter above (making sure to pass the collection of items you want to display) and call setListAdapter(...).

Have fun!

Answer (score 1):

Parse your data and store it into an [`ArrayList`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/ArrayList.html), then use a [`BaseAdapter`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html) for your `ListView`.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a an adapter for your ListView that is backed by any data structure that makes sense to you. The only requirement is that the adapter can interpret an item from the data source and produce a View that becomes a row in the ListView. I suggest you watch [The World of ListView](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70)

Answer (score 0):

you can use simple list adapter to show your data from the xml file .
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

```
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, 
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, 
            getResources().getStringArray(R.array.external xml file)));
}
```

Comment: Code only answers can usually benefit from some explanatory text to go along with the code.

Comment: thanks for the correction, will keep this in mind next time , just new here .